# Cutline mosaicing areal imagery with open source software

Tags: merge, image, image-mosaic, orthophoto

I'm very new in gis, and i'm trying to find a fast solution to merge 200 historical areal images(black and white from 1944). I orthorectified them manually, using gcp-s. They have 1 to 10 meters error. So I cannot use simple mosaicing software. I want to use roads as boundaries. Is there any os software what can help me in this? Or shell i cut them by myself, and merge them together with qgis for example?

Bonus question: Is there any automated contrast and brightness balancer for this amount of images?

Comment: I would check OSSIM.

Comment: Ask from the OSSIM mailing list if image linker exists or if some other binaries can do the same.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.